# Replacing text in an input box of a webpage (with defined ID)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fill up all the input fields of a webpage (having input IDs ending with txtValue) which are filled with the word ‘dog’ to be replaced with the word ‘cat’.
I have tried this code, but it isn’t working. Kindly help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

```
const ta = document.querySelectorAll("[id$='txtValue']");

const str = ta.value.replace("dog","cat");
ta.value = str
console.log(ta.value,"change to" ,str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelectorAll returns an array which needs to be iterated over.The replace method returns the modified string without changing the original.So,the following should work.

```
ta.forEach(elem => elem.value = elem.value.replace("dog","cat"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a list. So you need to iterate the list to set each value.

```js
const ta = document.querySelectorAll("[id$='txtValue']");

for (let i = 0; i <= ta.length; i++){
  const str = ta[i].value.replace("dog","cat");
  ta[i].value = str
}

console.log("finished");
```

Comment: Thank you . Your corrected code solved my querry.

Answer (score 0):

This code is the answer to the question.

```
const ta = document.querySelectorAll("[id$='txtValue']");

for (let i = 0; i <= ta.length; i++){
  const str = ta[i].value.replace("dog","cat");
  ta[i].value = str
}

console.log("finished");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).